# Xcode Build errors (newbie)

Tags: objective-c, xcode

## Here's my code:

(from SQLiteDB.h)

```
#import <sqlite3.h>


@interface SQLiteDB : NSObject {

    NSString *dbPath;
    int databaseKey;
    sqlite3 *db;
}

//@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *db;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *dbPath;
@property (nonatomic) sqlite3 *db;
@property (nonatomic) int databaseKey;
@end
```

===============
(from SQLiteDB.m)

```
#import "SQLiteDB.h"


@implementation SQLiteDB
@synthesize db, dbPath, databaseKey;
@end
```

===============
(from SampleAppDelegate.m)

```
#import "ReaderSampleAppDelegate.h"
#import "ReaderSampleViewController.h"

@implementation ReaderSampleAppDelegate

@synthesize window;
@synthesize viewController;


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Application lifecycle


- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application
{
    //  create the d/b or get the connection value
    SQLiteDB *dbInstance = [[SQLiteDB alloc] init];  //  Error here  <---------
}
```

==================

Error is: SQLiteDB undeclared.

I thought I did declare it in SQLiteDB.h?  How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
#import "SQLiteDB.h"
```

in SampleAppDelegate.m

Comment: +1 one for beating me by a minute and the other two by five seconds and seven seconds respectively.

Comment: I guess that should have been obvious, but since I'm a newbie and definitely struggeling with this, it isn't.  Thank you so much for your time.  :D

Answer (score 0):

In `SampleAppDelegate.m` include the following line:

```
#import "SQLiteDB.h"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need:

```
#import "SQLiteDB.h" in SampleAppDelegate.m or .h
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `#import SQLiteDB.h` into SampleAppDelegate.m

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to `#import "SQLiteDB.h"` in SampleAppDelegate.m